# Mysql two select statments union with order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

I'm trying to make a query to fetch products on my database based on a searcher's input. Supose the word entered on the searcher it's "stack overflow".

The query goes like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM products t1 
INNER JOIN products_references t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
INNER JOIN products_photo t3 ON t2.id = t3.id 
WHERE  
        (t2.name LIKE '%stack%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI
        OR t3.photo_name LIKE '%stack%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI
        ) 
    AND
        (
        t2.name LIKE '%overflow%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI
        OR t3.photo_name LIKE '%overflow%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI
        )

ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN (t2.name LIKE '%stack%') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
CASE WHEN (t3.photo_name LIKE '%stack%' OR t3.photo_name LIKE '%overflow%' ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
) as a 
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM products t1 
INNER JOIN products_references t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
INNER JOIN products_photo t3 ON t2.id = t3.id 
WHERE  
        (t2.name LIKE '%stack%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI
        OR t3.photo_name LIKE '%stack%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI
        ) 
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN (t2.name LIKE '%stack%' ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
CASE WHEN (t3.photo_name LIKE '%stack%' ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
) as b LIMIT 0,10
```

What I want to archive:

- Get the results of the first query and then the results of the second, ordered on the own rules of each query.
- Drop away repited rows that already appear on the first query.

Example:

Table A results

- stack overflow mysql
- stack overflow jquery

Table B results

- stack something
- stack overflow jquery
- stack it all

Final result

- stack overflow mysql
- stack overflow jquery
- stack overflow something
- stack it all

What I'm getting now as a result is a mix not ordered as I want. Any idea?

**Edit**

I have tried spencer7593 solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM products t1 
JOIN products_references t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
JOIN products_photo t3 ON t2.id = t3.id 
WHERE t2.name       LIKE '%stack%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI 
  OR t3.photo_name LIKE '%stack%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI
ORDER
  BY CASE WHEN (t2.name       LIKE '%stack%' ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  CASE WHEN (t3.photo_name LIKE '%stack%' OR t3.photo_name LIKE '%overflow%' ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  CASE WHEN (t3.photo_name LIKE '%stack%' ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

The main problem here is that the two queries order by the first word first ( '%stack%' in the example above). As the first query is in a way a subset of the second, ordering all together change the order. How can I join this two queries to maintain the same order given as they were individual queries?

Comment: If the results exist in both, show A records before B records?  Since the outer select isn't ordered, results can be returned in whatever order the engine desires.  order by on subqueries only matters when you're using a limit. which doesn't appear to be the case here so they serve no purpose other than to slow down the results.  To get the desired results, you'd have to order the outer query.

Comment: Yes. I will try to explain it better. I would like to show first the A's records and before all of them show all B records. If records exists on A I don't want to show them again. I do use a limit on the outer query tough, does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL optimizes away the ORDER BY clauses in the inline views when there isn't an ORDER BY on the outer query.  (The ORDER BY clauses in the inline views are not optimized away if the view query includes a LIMIT clause; but don't give any guarantee about the order the rows returned by the outer query.)

If you want the rows returned in a particular sequence, add an ORDER BY on the outermost query.

Reference:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

---

> Use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore, the use of ORDER BY in this context is typically in conjunction with LIMIT, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows to retrieve for the SELECT, even though it does not necessarily affect the order of those rows in the final UNION result. If ORDER BY appears without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it will have no effect anyway.
>
> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one.

---

As far as ordering rows in the outer query, we could include a "discriminator column" that tells us which query returned a row. In this example, we are returning literal value '1' on rows returned by the first query, and literal value '2' on rows returned by the second query:

```
 ( SELECT '1' AS src, f.* FROM ... ORDER BY ... )
 UNION ALL
 ( SELECT '2' AS src, s.* FROM ... ORDER BY ... )
 ORDER BY src, ...
```

But with those distinct values, we wouldn't be able to get duplicates removed with DISTINCT, or give preference to keeping the row from the first query.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The only differences I'm seeing between the two queries being union-ed is the ORDER BY clauses, and this part of the WHERE clause

```
AND
    (
    t2.name LIKE '%overflow%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI
    OR t3.photo_name LIKE '%overflow%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI
    )
```

Looks like the first query returns a subset of rows returned by the second.

So, I'm not seeing why this needs to be two separate queries.

Couldn't we just run one query, which includes rows that would be returned by the second query, then return the rows that would have been returned by just the first query first.

We can move that condition from the WHERE clause, and order by that first; make that the first expression in the ORDER BY clause.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM products t1 
    JOIN products_references t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
    JOIN products_photo t3 ON t2.id = t3.id 
   WHERE t2.name       LIKE '%stack%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI 
      OR t3.photo_name LIKE '%stack%' COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI
   ORDER
      BY CASE WHEN (t2.name       LIKE '%overflow%' OR t3.photo_name LIKE '%overflow%') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       , CASE WHEN (t2.name       LIKE '%stack%'    OR t3.photo_name LIKE '%overflow%') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       , CASE WHEN (t3.photo_name LIKE '%stack%'    OR t3.photo_name LIKE '%overflow%') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       , CASE WHEN (t2.name       LIKE '%stack%'                                      ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       , CASE WHEN (t3.photo_name LIKE '%stack%'                                      ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

That first expression in the ORDER BY clause will evaluate to TRUE only for row that would have been returned by the first query.

If we want duplicate rows eliminated, we can add the DISTINCT keyword after SELECT, or add an appropriate GROUP BY clause.

And add back in any `COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI` that are needed.

Comment: I've got a typo on the code. What if the first order clause of the two queries just filter the first word? Getting all the '%stack%' rows will cause an unwanted order because the second query will give more rows.

Comment: @Sergi: I think I answered part of the question you asked... if you combine two queries with a UNION/UNION ALL operator, and you want the results ordered... add an ORDER BY on the outer query. To discriminate between rows returned by the first query from rows returned by the second query, add a discriminator column, an extra column that tells which query returned a particular row. To exclude rows from the second query, add predicates (conditions) to exclude those rows.

Comment: @Sergi: In the FOLLOWUP, I was addressing a different issue, a different question... how to return the specified resultset without using a UNION/UNION ALL of two queries, but instead using a *single* query, and in the ORDER BY clause using expressions that will get the rows returned in the required order.